# Windows XP - mapping network drive

Tags: windows-xp, credentials

I have mapped a network drive and named S:\ under "My Computer".

My problem is that I need to log in to the drive again when I reboot my pc, how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**
My pc is Windows XP Professional Version 2002 Service Pack 3
The share driver is using Windows Server 2008

**UPDATE 2**
I have not joined the domain
I log in the server drive with domain account
I have read/write permission

Comment: Which edition and service pack of XP are you on? Which edition and service pack of Windows is the share living on? Do you have matching accounts set up on both machines if you're not on a domain?

Comment: Please see my update. Yes, I have a matching account, just wonder why I need to log in again when reboot

Comment: Severely lacking information! Are either of the computers on a domain? what account are you logging on with (local or domain), what are the share permissions configured as? - I'm thinking that all you need to do is tick the 'Remember my password' checkbox, but that seems too obvious. More detail will really increase your chances of somebody being able to help you.

Comment: Sorry for the insufficient information, please see update 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map the share with a batch file in your startup folder

> net use s: //pathto/share password /user:domain\user

Answer (score 1):

try running:

```
rundll32 keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr
```

there you can type credentials [to authenticate against remote severs] that will be stored

Answer (score 1):

You can do that as a batch file as in the accepted answer, or you can more simply make the mapping persistent:

net use s: //pathto/share password /user:domain\user /PERSISTENT:YES